# Killing Vectors from Killing Equations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, vector-fields

I need to find the killing vectors of the FLRW metric. However, it seems that they are complicated. Is there a simple/general equation that gives the killing vectors for a given metric? Or do I have to solve ten independent killing equations simultaneously to find the killing vectors?

Comment: For a _general_ metric, there's no simple approach, although you can easily prove in the $n$-dimensional case there are at most $\tfrac12n(n+1)$ linearly independent KV fields. For FLRW metrics, the result is in Sec. 5 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.07142.pdf).

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: Sec. 5 doesn't provide a full selection. Ultimately, Sec. 7 presents a conjecture about the result in comoving coordinates. So your question was only answerable as of 2015 if you specify a more tractable coordinate system.

Comment: @J.G. I see then the problem sees hard to solve..